# What paragon paths and epic destinies grant wings or flight?

Tags: dnd-4e, paragon-path, flight

In D&D 4th edition, which paragon paths and epic destinies grant wings or flight?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Paragon paths:

  - results for Flight:

    - Dragonborn Scion of Arkosia: Blood of Io (16th level): You gain overland flight with a speed of 12.
    - Dragonborn Honorable blade: Fly/encounter as utility 12
    - Dragonborn Storm Dragon: Storm Dragon Wings (16th level): You gain overland flight with a speed of 8.
    - Whirlwind Genasi: Whirlwind Breeze (11th level): When you use the windwalker encounter power, you gain a fly speed of 8 until the end of your next turn.
  - results for fly:

    - Incandescent champion: level 20 daily until end of encounter
    - Favored Soul:     Heaven's Boon (16th level): A pair of feathery wings unfolds from your back, and you gain a fly speed of 6. You can use this speed only if you are wearing no armor or light armor.
    - Unveiled Visage: Soaring Charge (11th level): When you charge, you can fly your speed as part of the charge. You also gain a +2 bonus to all defenses against opportunity attacks you provoke while moving during the charge. 20th level daily fly until end of encounter.
    - Building Thunder: Daily 20 rage
    - Storm Disciple: Encounter: Effect: You gain a fly speed equal to your speed and can hover. This effect lasts until an attack hits you or until the end of the encounter. When the effect ends, you descend to the ground without taking falling damage.
    - Scourge of Io: daily 20 fly, gain wings
    - Angelic Avenger: daily 20 fly, gain glowy wings
    - Platinum Templar: encounter fly,
    - Storm Speaker: fly on AP
    - Whirling samara:  Spinning Wings (16th level): When you change from humanoid form to your beast form on your turn, you gain a fly speed equal to your speed until the end of your turn.
    - Sky Hunter: fly on AP
    - Ocular Adept: fly/2 encounter
    - Lyrandar Wind-Rider: fly on AP, daily fly until end of encounter sustain minor
    - Initiate of the Dragon: fly 1/encounter, daily fly
    - Four Winds Master:  Mysteries Revealed (16th level): ... In addition, whenever you shift, you can instead fly the same distance. If you don’t land at the end of this movement, you fall.
    - Legendary Hexblade, gloom pact, daily fly
    - Uncarnate: daily fly, can't take standard actions
    - Avenging Haunt: Daily fly, sustain standard
    - Arcane Wellspring: encounter fly
    - Praetor Legate: encounter fly
    - Hellborn Shadow: encounter fly
    - Storm Sentinel: encounter fly
    - Radiant serpent: fly on AP
    - Student of Caiphon: encounter fly
    - Astral Ascendant: daily fly
      *
- Epic Destiny:

  - results for Flight

    - Prison of the Winds: Level 26 utility daily flight as stance
    - Glorious Spirit: IR flight, at will, toward specific enemy
  - results for fly:

    - Twilight tribune: daily fly 26
    - Storm Soverign: fly speed level 30
    - Heir of Siberys: daily fly 26 ( mark of storm)
    - Avangion: fly speed level 24 (wings)
    - Exalted Angel: fly speed level 21 (wings)
    - Primal Avatar: daily fly 26
    - Dragon King: fly speed 24 (draconic transformation, so probably wings)
    - Disincarnate: fly on death, level 24
    - Avatar of IO, fly speed 24 (wings)
    - Master Hierophant: daily fly 26
    - Bahamut's Vessel: fly speed 30 on death (wings, become platinum dragon)
    - Avatar of Storm: Fly speed 30
    - Draconic incarnation: daily fly 26, turn into dragon
  - Wings without flight

    - dragonheart